# problem insert timestamp value to Postgresql table using R

Tags: r, postgresql

```
datecolumn <- format(Sys.time())
qry = sprintf("insert into table(column1, datecolumn) values(%s, %s);", 123234,datecolumn)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, qry)
print(rs)

Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "14"
LINE 1: ...datecolumn) values(123234, 2022-09-13 14:26:4);

> format(Sys.time())
[1] "2022-09-13 14:26:44"
```

It works When I use literal values:

```
enter code here`sprintf("insert into table(column1, datecolumn) values(%s, %s);", 123234,'2022-09-13 14:08:08')
```

but getting error when i use variables.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are inserting in that format:

```
insert into test1 (pdate1) values (2022-09-13 14:26:4)
```

This is incorrect syntax, you must use

```
insert into test1 (pdate1) values ('2022-09-13 14:26:4')
```

Comment: i understand it should be quoted. how could i quote a variable like
 pdate1 <- format(Sys.time())
 insert into test1 (pdate1) values ('pdate1') it would take like values('pdate1') not  like('2022-09-13 14:26:4'') Don't know what is missing here!